# The Android SDK root folder 'platform-tools' does not exist on the local file system

Tags: android, appium

I have done the ANDROID_HOME setup, but I think it's not able to read the SDK files, getting below added error in Appium Server:
`Encountered internal error running command: Error: The Android SDK root folder 'platform-tools' does not exist on the local file system. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details`

I have added all, ANDROID_HOME path with platform-tools, build-tools, and tools under the System Variables.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: have you imported your project?

Answer (score 0):

I got it config here `C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` and the others like this `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin`, `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\tools`, `%ANDROID_HOME%platform-tools`.

I didn't saw you mention the bin one so don't know if that could also make any change, but I got it included and have no issues.